# How can I rotate vectors onto a Basemap map projection?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making wind vector barb plots using the matplotlib barb function and basemap in python.
I have a list of vectors (wind observations) at arbitrary latitudes and longitudes, i.e. not on a regular grid.

I need to rotate the vectors onto the map projection before plotting or the barbs point in the wrong direction. What is the best way to do this?

e.g.

```
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define locations of my vectors
lat = numpy.array([50.1,46.2,51.6,52.2,54.4])
lon = numpy.array([-3.3,-1.0,-5.2,-1.2,0.2])

# Define some east-west vectors to illustrate the problem
u = numpy.array([5,5,5,5,5])
v = numpy.array([0,0,0,0,0])

# Set up map projection
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-15.,llcrnrlat=46.,urcrnrlon=15.,urcrnrlat=59.,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=40.,lat_2=50.,lon_0=-50.,
            resolution ='l')

# Calculate positions of vectors on map projection 
x,y = m(lon,lat)

# Draw barbs
m.barbs(x,y,u,v, length=7, color='red')

# Draw some grid lines for reference
parallels = numpy.arange(-80.,90,20.)
meridians = numpy.arange(0.,360.,20.)
m.drawparallels(parallels)
m.drawmeridians(meridians)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Note that in the plot, the vectors do not point east-west.

I have tried using the rotate_vector and transform_vector routines, but these only work for gridded vector data.

Is there a routine to rotate the vectors onto the map projection for an arbitrary list of lat,lon u,v pairs?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're specifying your `u` and `v` in lat, long. At the same time, you're specifying your `x` and `y` in map coordinates.  `barbs` seems to expect both of them in map coordinates, rather than a mix.

The simplest way is to just calculate the endpoints to get the components.  (My description makes no sense, so here's what I had in mind:)

```
x, y = m(lon, lat)
x1, y1 = m(lon+u, lat+v)
u_map, v_map = x1-x, y1-y
```

You'll then need to rescale the magnitudes, as well.  As a full example:

```
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define locations of my vectors
lat = numpy.array([50.1,46.2,51.6,52.2,54.4])
lon = numpy.array([-3.3,-1.0,-5.2,-1.2,0.2])

# Define some east-west vectors to illustrate the problem
u = numpy.array([5,5,5,5,5])
v = numpy.array([0,0,0,0,0])

# Set up map projection
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-15.,llcrnrlat=46.,urcrnrlon=15.,urcrnrlat=59.,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=40.,lat_2=50.,lon_0=-50.,
            resolution ='l')

# Calculate positions of vectors on map projection 
x,y = m(lon,lat)

# Calculate the orientation of the vectors
x1, y1 = m(lon+u, lat+v)
u_map, v_map = x1-x, y1-y

# Rescale the magnitudes of the vectors...
mag_scale = np.hypot(u_map, v_map) / np.hypot(u, v)
u_map /= mag_scale
v_map /= mag_scale

# Draw barbs
m.barbs(x,y,u_map,v_map, length=7, color='red')

# Draw some grid lines for reference
parallels = numpy.arange(-80.,90,20.)
meridians = numpy.arange(0.,360.,20.)
m.drawparallels(parallels)
m.drawmeridians(meridians)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For people with gridded data who stumpled upon this question

Rather use the built-in function rotate_vector, you can find it here:

http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html